# Symfony3 LDAP configuration

Tags: php, ldap, symfony

I am trying to config Symfony3 so that I can authenticate users using LDAP. I mean looking at google search and symfony docs there is very limited informations and based what I have seen it is not very informative at all.

What i need is: Symfony3 to connect to LDAP server and fetch users based on username and password params.

I know this i probably very wide questions, but given on limited info on how to sync this functionality with Symfony3. Would like you guis to give me some idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Following this tutorial: https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/how-use-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php/

You dont need use LDAP config that symfony supported. You can integrate this code into your symfony's function.